# How to get dynamic id´s in a "foreach" data-bind for a sortable accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery-ui-sortable

Hi I want to use a sortable accordion (http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#sortable )
together with the knockout-js "data-bind: foreach"-loop.

For each loop my  will need a unique "id", but how do I generate that for the jQuery to process?

Knockoutcode:

```
self.Tasks = ko.observableArray(); // has TaskId, Taskname, Description...
```

HTML-ACCORDIAN:

```
        <div id="accordion" data-bind="foreach: Tasks">
            <div id="THIS HAS TO BE DYNAMICALLY GENERATED???" class="group">
                <h3><b><span data-bind="text: Taskname"></span></b></h3>
                <div>
                    <textarea name="Description" data-bind="value: Description"></textarea>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
```

The javascript is:

```
$(function() {

    $( "#accordion" )
      .accordion({
          header: "> div > h3"  
      })
      .sortable({
        axis: "y",
        handle: "h3",
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            var items=[];
            ui.item.siblings().andSelf().each( function(){
                //compare data('index') and the real index
                if($(this).data('index')!=$(this).index()){
                    items.push(this.id);
                }
            });
            // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
            // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
            ui.item.children( "h3" ).triggerHandler( "focusout" );
            // Print out the sequence of tasks for further processing
            if(items.length) $("#sequence").text(items.join(',')); 
            ui.item.parent().trigger('stop');
        } 
    })
    .on('stop',function(){
          $(this).siblings().andSelf().each(function(i){
              $(this).data('index',i);
          });
      })
      .trigger('stop');
  });
```

A part of me tells me this should be easy, but I´m obviously to thick to figure it out.
Anybody have a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the $index() keyword.

Although I am not sure of the syntax, something like the code below may be put you on the right track

```
<div id="accordion" data-bind="foreach: Tasks">
        <div data-bind="attr : {'id': $index()}" class="group">
            <h3><b><span data-bind="text: Taskname"></span></b></h3>
            <div>
                <textarea name="Description" data-bind="value: Description"></textarea>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

As asked below using TaskId

```
<div id="accordion" data-bind="foreach: Tasks">
        <div data-bind="attr : {'id': TaskId}" class="group">
            <h3><b><span data-bind="text: Taskname"></span></b></h3>
            <div>
                <textarea name="Description" data-bind="value: Description"></textarea>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could I use the "data-bind=`attr:..." with a ko.observable, as my TaskId?

Comment: if the observable is on your viewmodel then you could, for example  `data-bind="attr : {'id': TaskId}"`

Comment: Just one more thing;) Seems some browsers are not to happy about ids staring with a number. Could I somehow workaround this in my html code or do I need a "ko"-helper where I create a string based upon my TaskId?



I´m thinking something along: data-bind="attr : {'id': 'task_no_' + TaskId}"